# MS Access: Unzip a document stored as BLOB in memory using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, zip, ms-access-2007

I have an MS Access table which stores zipped text documents in a BLOB column (long binary data) named XML. Each blob contains the binary representation of a zip archive (deflate) containing exactly one document named DOCUMENT. I would like to read the contents of the BLOB, unzip it and return the contents of DOCUMENT as a string in VBA, without the need to cache and unzip the archive on disk (I have managed to do that, but the process is very slow and inelegant).

I have tried downloading and referencing zlibwapi.dll as suggested here: [`http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/excel/318843-uncompress-compressed-string-using-zlib-vba.html`](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/excel/318843-uncompress-compressed-string-using-zlib-vba.html)

The DLL calls seem to work, but unfortunately I cannot get the code to unzip my data:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE REFERENCE_ID = 28804")


    Dim aByteData() As Byte
    Dim sStringData As String
    Dim res As Variant


    With rs
        .MoveFirst
        While Not .EOF

            aByteData = rs!xml

            res = DecompressData(aByteData, rs!xml_lu)


            .MoveNext
        Wend

        .Close
    End With

    Set rs = Nothing
    MsgBox "Done.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Before calling DecompressData, aByteData contains the correct sequence of bytes of my zipped document. After calling DecompressData, res is equal to -3 and aByteData is an array of zeroes.

Does anyone out there have any experience with zlibwapi.dll and how to get it to work in VBA?  Any idea what exit code -3 means?

**Update:**

This fork of minizip seems to go in the right direction, though I have to idea of how to get it to work in VBA:
https://github.com/nmoinvaz/minizip

Comment: From the link in your question, you'll see that DecompressData calls the library function Uncompress.  I downloaded the latest zlib source and inspected `zlib.h` file.  If you do the same, search for `Z_DATA_ERROR`, which is the constant equal to -3 returned by UncompressData.  There are various code comments detailing reasons for Z_DATA_ERROR results.  No, this doesn't resolve the problem and is the dirty way to go about finding the information, but hope it helps get you started on finding a resolution.

Comment: Also consider the information at [here](https://www.zlib.net/zlib_faq.html#faq11) and [there](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html).  If your data is equivalent to a zip file then you may need to use minizip functionality (which zlibwapi.dll supposedly contains).  Sorry, that's about all I can comment on now, but I hope it helps.

Comment: @CPerkins: Thanks, it's definitely a start! Do you happen to know whether there is any way to recognize if a file is equivalent to zip just by analyzing its binary data (e.g. magic bytes)? The problem is that I'm pulling the data from a third party Sybase database into Access and there is no way of knowing what method is used for compression.

Comment: I just did a web search and found https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/digformatspecs/APPNOTE%2820120901%29_Version_6.3.3.txt and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#Structure.  The first four "magic" bytes should equal `0x04034b50` if it's a standard zip file.  If it's a gz file (what zlib compresses) or anything else, not sure.  You'd have to pull the first few bytes from your data to compare to each other and do a search.

Comment: Besides, doesn't the fact that you can save to disk and extract that way tell you something about the format?  I suppose you could load it up in various zip programs (7zip?) and it'd give you detail of the format.

Comment: I checked and the file does indeed start with those numbers, though in reverse order: 50 4b 03 04. Perhaps a question of endianness? I'll give minizip a try, though I'm not exactly sure about which functions I have to call, and how. Maybe the source code will give some hints.

Comment: So I took a closer look at unzip.h and unzip.c provided by MiniZip. I am no C expert, but from what I could gather the library is only able to handle decompression of files, and not byte arrays as zLib is (through the function `uncompress`). I hope to be mistaken...